# Replacing dataSource in @angular:material:table

Tags: angular, typescript

i am a newcomer angular users. i just learn how to generate angular material schematic table with using @angular/material:table. recently, i just wanna to replace all data from datasource with my angular-in-memory-web-api data source that i just made. but, there's sneaky error that tellin me "expected 1 arguments, but got 0" in user-table.components.ts (i made bold font for the error occurs in vscode)

here's my code

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../user-skeleton';
import { UsersService } from '../users.service';


/**
 * Data source for the UserTable view. This class should
 * encapsulate all logic for fetching and manipulating the displayed data
 * (including sorting, pagination, and filtering).
 */
export class UserTableDataSource extends DataSource<User>{
  data: User[] = [];
  paginator: MatPaginator | undefined;
  sort: MatSort | undefined;

  constructor(
    private userService: UsersService
    ) {
      super();
    }

  getUsers(): void{
    this.userService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(data => this.data = data)
  }

  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<User[]> {
    if (this.paginator && this.sort) {
      return merge(observableOf(this.data), this.paginator.page, this.sort.sortChange)
        .pipe(map(() => {
          return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data ]));
        }));
    } else {
      throw Error('Please set the paginator and sort on the data source before connecting.');
    }
  }

  disconnect(): void {}

  private getPagedData(data: User[]): User[] {
    if (this.paginator) {
      const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
      return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sort the data (client-side). If you're using server-side sorting,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getSortedData(data: User[]): User[] {
    if (!this.sort || !this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort?.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort?.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'id': return compare(+a.id, +b.id, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

function compare(a: string | number, b: string | number, isAsc: boolean): number {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

and here is my user-table.compoents.ts

```
    import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import { User } from '../user-skeleton';
import { UsersService } from '../users.service';
import { UserTableDataSource } from './user-table-datasource';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-table',
  templateUrl: './user-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-table.component.css']
})
export class UserTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<User>;
  dataSource: UserTableDataSource;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'gender'];

  constructor(
    private userService: UsersService
  ) {
    this.dataSource = **new UserTableDataSource();**
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

any help would be really appreciated! thanks community :)

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz example so we can reproduce and fix the issue? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `user-table.component.ts` file. Please changed as like below because your `UserTableDataSource` is argumented constructor due to that we need to pass the instance of `UsersService` while we create a new instance.

```
constructor(private userService: UsersService) {
    this.dataSource = **new UserTableDataSource(this.userService);**
}
```

instead of

```
constructor(private userService: UsersService) {
    this.dataSource = **new UserTableDataSource();**
}
```